# How to return index of item in MultiDimensional Array and check attributes of those items

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, attributeerror

I'm having trouble iterating through a multidimensional array and returning the index of the elements. What I am doing is creating a MoveUp function that moves through the multidimentional array.

Currently my find method will return the correct index of the objects in the first array within the multidimensional arrays first index. The rest of the items outside the multidimensional array will return an error:

```
UnboundLocalError: 'local variable 'column' refrenced before assignment'
```

Also in the MoveUp function I get an error. I set one item in the field array to "Active" and I want that to be the starting point to move up in the array. But for some reason my code gives me this error.

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'status'


    class Square:       
    def SetName(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def SetOwner(self,name):
        self.controlled_by = name

    def SetLED(self, name):
        self.led = name

    def SetPosition(self, position):
        self.posiion = position

    def SetStatus(self, status):
                self.status = status

B1_A = Square()
B1_A.SetName("B_R1_A")
B1_A.SetOwner("Open")
B1_A.SetLED("Off")
B1_A.SetStatus("UnActive")

B1_B = Square()
B1_B.SetName("B_R1_B")
B1_B.SetOwner("Open")
B1_B.SetLED("Off")
B1_B.SetStatus("UnActive")

B2_A = Square()
B2_A.SetName("B_R2_A")
B2_A.SetOwner("Open")
B2_A.SetLED("Off")
B2_A.SetStatus("UnActive")

B2_B = Square()
B2_B.SetName("R_R2_B")
B2_B.SetOwner("Open")
B2_B.SetLED("Off")
B2_B.SetStatus("UnActive")

B3_A = Square()
B3_A.SetName("R_R3_A")
B3_A.SetOwner("Open")
B3_A.SetLED("Off")
B3_A.SetStatus("UnActive")

R1_A = Square()
R1_A.SetName("R_R1_A")
R1_A.SetOwner("Open")
R1_A.SetLED("Off")
R1_A.SetStatus("UnActive")

R1_B = Square()
R1_B.SetName("R_R1_B")
R1_B.SetOwner("Open")
R1_B.SetLED("Off")
R1_B.SetStatus("UnActive")

R2_A = Square()
R2_A.SetName("R_R2_A")
R2_A.SetOwner("Open")
R2_A.SetLED("Off")
R2_A.SetStatus("UnActive")

R2_B = Square()
R2_B.SetName("R_R2_B")
R2_B.SetOwner("Open")
R2_B.SetLED("Off")
R2_B.SetStatus("UnActive")

R3_A = Square()
R3_A.SetName("R_R3_A")
R3_A.SetOwner("Open")
R3_A.SetLED("Off")
R3_A.SetStatus("UnActive")

# MultiDimensional Array
Field = [[B1_A,B1_B],[B2_A,B2_B],[B3_A],[R3_A],[R2_A,R2_B],[R1_A,R1_B]]

#Find Index of Element in MultiDimenstional Array
def find(l, elem):
    for row, i in enumerate(l):
        try:
            column = i.index(elem)
            return row, column
        except ValueError:
                return row, column
        return -1

print(find(Field, B1_A)) #Returns (0,0) Correct
print(find(Field, B1_B)) #Returns (0,1) Correct
#print(find(Field, B2_B)) #Throws Error

# Set a Square Status Active
B1_B.status ="Active"

def MoveUp():
        #Iterate through each item in Field
        for i in Field:
                #if item status equal to Active
                if i.status == "Active":
                        #if item index 3 item in the multidimensional array
                        if find(Field, i) == (2,0):
                        #current position is this index
                          current_position = (find(Field, i))
                          print(current_position)
                          #new position is this index + 1
                          new_position = current_position + 1
                          #old position if new position - 1
                          old_position = new_position - 1
                          #Set the servos status in the new postion to Active
                          Field(new_position).status = "Active"
                          #Set the servos status in the old position to UnActive
                          Field(old_position).status = "UnActive"

                        else:
                           #current position is this index
                           current_position = (find(Field, i))
                           #new position is this index + 2
                           new_position = current_position + 2
                           #old position if new position - 2
                           old_position = new_position - 2
                           #Set the servos status in the new postion to Active
                           Field(new_position).status = "Active"
                           #Set the servos status in the old position to UnActive
                           Field(old_position).status = "UnActive"

MoveUp()
```

Answer (score 0):

First error you have because you trying to return not existed value.

```
#Find Index of Element in MultiDimenstional Array
def find(l, elem):
    for row, i in enumerate(l):
        try:
            column = i.index(elem)
            return row, column
        except ValueError:
            #here is error column not exists.
            #return row, column 
            pass    

            #becouse it's normal that one of array don't have needed item
            #you should pass


    return -1

print(find(Field, B1_A)) #Returns (0,0) Correct
print(find(Field, B1_B)) #Returns (0,1) Correct
print(find(Field, B2_B)) #will Return (1,1)
```

Second error you have because you trying to use 2d array as 1d.

```
def MoveUp():

    #Iterate through each item in Field
    for SubFields in Field: 
        #Every Field item is Array of Fields 
        #ie [B1_A,B1_B] You need to iterator over this sub field.
        for i in SubFields:
            #if item status equal to Active

            if i.status == "Active":
                #if item index 3 item in the multidimensional array
                if find(Field, i) == (2,0):
                    #current position is this index
                    current_position = (find(Field, i))
                    print(current_position)
                    #new position is this index + 1

                    # here is another error, but you will not get it with you test data
                    #current_position is tuple (2, 0)
                    #you can't add 1 to tuple
                    #I don't know what you trying to do here, so can't help with it.
                    new_position = current_position + 1 #ERROR!!!
                    #old position if new position - 1
                    old_position = new_position - 1 
                    #Set the servos status in the new postion to Active
                    Field(new_position).status = "Active" #also error Field is array not function
                    #Set the servos status in the old position to UnActive
                    Field(old_position).status = "UnActive"

                else:
                    #current position is this index
                    current_position = (find(Field, i))
```

UPDATE: If you want to find (and get) items in array with any depth try this:

```
#really crazy multidimensional array
Field = [ [ B1_A ],
          [
              [ [B1_B],
                [[B2_A]] ],
              [ [B2_B, B3_A] ]
          ],
          [[ [ [[R3_A]] ],
             [ [[R2_A],[R2_B]] ] ]] ]

def find(l, needle):
    """Search for needle in l. 
       If found returns path to needle, otherwise return empty array"""

    def find_path( l, needle ):
        """Search for needle in l. 
           If found returns reversed path to needle, otherwise return empty array"""
        for index, item in enumerate(l):
            if type(item) is list:
                sub_path = find_path( item, needle )
                if sub_path:
                    sub_path.append( index )
                    return sub_path
            elif item == needle:
                return [ index ]

        return []


    path = find_path( l, needle )
    path.reverse()
    return path

def get_by_path( l, path ):
    """Get element of list l by it's path.
       If path is incorrect throw IndexError"""
    item = l
    for i in path:
        item = item[i]
    return item

print( find( Field, B3_A ) ) # print [1, 1, 0, 1]
print( get_by_path( Field, find( Field, B3_A ) ).name ) #print R_R3_A

print( find( Field, R2_B ) ) # print [2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
print( get_by_path( Field, [2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0] ).name )  #print R_R2_B
```

Comment: Update: added function that may search and retrieve items in multidimensional list